# How do I update to minecraft java 1.18 WITHOUT altering old terrain?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, technical-issues

I want to update my 1.17.1 survival vanilla world to minecraft 1.19 when it comes out and I can't find anywhere a way to update so that worlds don't modify existing terrain, I only want to get the new stuff in new chunks.
I don't care about ugly chunk borders or anything like that, I just need a way to keep my chunks as they are right now.
the closest I've seen to what I'm looking for is a small remark in [here](https://help.minecraft.net/hc/en-us/articles/4415035909261-Caves-Cliffs-Part-II-Upgrading-Existing-Worlds) where they say:

> Players who have opened a world with the Caves & Cliffs Experimental Toggle enabled when bedrock was still generating at y=0 will not receive new world generation features

but they don't go any further in the topic and searching for it I only get results for bedrock edition.

I also don't mind hopping between snapshots as long as they don't cause any nasty permanent side effects to worldgen other than what I'm looking for.

Comment: Does this help? [How to reset chunks](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://m.youtube.com/watch%3Fv%3DkuOhihQcASs&ved=2ahUKEwiascqk0P73AhU94XMBHUT3DXsQwqsBegQIBhAF&usg=AOvVaw0VsUU70HkMNTvaYioRXkez)

Comment: There should be something about blending data in each chunk's NBT inside the region files that tells it whether to add new stuff below or not. Changing that for every chunk manually would of course be a lot of effort, so a tool would be better. I've seen some NBT editing libraries for various programming languages, but haven't tried any of them yet.

Comment: @DialFros thanks but that seems to be about deleting already generated chunks, not preserving them

Comment: This is the default option. Minecraft keeps old terrain the same (other then bedrock), it simply geneerates new chunks differently and adds new buildable space below Y=0, and populates that space.

Comment: @valkyrie_pilot the bedrock and the void below it is what i want to preserve, I want the bedrock layer to be at y=0 and nothing below it, the default is changing everything below Y=0 up to Y=-64

Comment: There isn't an option for it in the vanilla game. I'm sure there's a mod for it, though.